# Reading CSV - Beginner

Tags: python

I have been trying to read a csv file from my desktop and have not been successful.  I checked my current working directory and it is pointed to my desktop, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.  Below is the module I used and the error output that I received.  I am using Python 3.2.3

```
import csv  
reader = csv.reader(open(name.csv, mode = 'r'))  
for row in reader:  
    print (row)
```

Here is my result

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/FileName.py", line 2,in 
>       reader = csv.reader(open(name.csv, mode = 'r'))
>   NameError: name 'Beta' is not defined

Help?  Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing of python but sounds like one of your values in the csv file is 'beta' ?

Comment: Do you have `name.csv` or `"name.csv"`?

Comment: I think OP has defined `name = "Beta"` and is trying to call `open(name.csv)`. Try `open("Beta.csv")` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
import csv
with open('name.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: @user2014684 You should repay kindness with a lovely green checkmark. :)